# Adding Task Outcomes SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have two sites and one of them is a sandbox site. When I create a custom workflow and add the Start Approval Process on the non-sandbox site I cannot add any Task Outcomes, but for the sandbox site I can add Task Outcomes withe no problem.

My administrator has given me owner permissions over the site collection but that still doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try deactivating all of the workflow services in the Site Collection Features and the Site Features. Then try again. You may need to restart Designer after you do this.

*EDIT: Also, the workflow sometimes does this when there are custom content types involved. You may need to remove all custom content types that are not being used and re-associate your workflow to a new tasks list. Try the service restarts I listed above first though.*

Comment: I must not have enough permissions on the site collection level to deactivate and restart these features.